# how to access properties stored in a .properties file in a python file using ConfigParser

Tags: python, properties, config, configparser

I have a .properties file which contains data. I am trying to access these properties from a python file.

My properties file looks something like this:

```
[section1]
header = time, date, name, process_name, location

[section2]
content = timestamp, details
```

I am using ConfigParser in python and I wanna access the properties like that:

```
config.get("section1", header[0])
config.get("section2", content[2])
```

But right now, I am getting this error: " global name 'header' is not defined
"

How do I resolve this error or how do I go about using the position number to reference the particular property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.get('section1', 'header')` will return `'time, date, name, process_name, location'`.
Then you use `split` to break it down into `['time', 'date', 'name', 'process_name', 'location']`.

```
print(config.get('section1', 'header').split(', ')[0])
# time

print(config.get('section2', 'content').split(', ')[1])
# details
```